# How to break down a JSON column within a data frame into usable portions?

Tags: python, json, jupyter

I have a data set that lists match details for games of Teamfight Tactics, and one of the columns has something like this in each cell:

```
{'Cybernetic': 1, 'Demolitionist': 1, 'Infiltrator': 1, 'Rebel': 1, 'Set3_Brawler': 1, 'Set3_Celestial': 1, 'Set3_Void': 1, 'Sniper': 1}
```

I am trying to break this down into multiple columns so that I can perform analysis. The keys are synergies and the labels are the number of combinations.

There is another column with a similar format:

```
{'Ziggs': {'items': [7], 'star': 1}, 'Ashe': {'items': [9], 'star': 1}, 'ChoGath': {'items': [6], 'star': 1}, 'Ekko': {'items': [1], 'star': 1}}
```

Where the values are the champion's name, the number of items, and the stars of the unit (3 copies of 1 unit --> 2 star unit, up to 3)

I have tried using json_loads, json_normalize, etc... and have had little luck. If it matters at all, I am just reading CSVs directly into Jupyter.

Any help would be appreciated, I am just really struggling to break this down into a usable format.

Comment: please share the expected output how you want to see your results, question is not much clear as of now

Comment: what problem are you trying to solve? If the file is valid json, json.loads will give you a dictionary with the same structure you show. I would recommend working with this structure for whatever task you have, is there a reason you are looking for a transformation?

Comment: Ah, you are working with pandas (you should add the tag, and mention it explicitly in the question), so you want a tabular-friendly layout, right? How did you try to use json_normalize, and how does it fall short?